# ftp_nlist() not working in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ftp, google-cloud-platform

There is a bug where ftp_nlist() in PHP GAE fails to work sometimes.

I have a scheduled task (cron) that will regularly check a remote FTP server for any new events and download the files. Yes, I am using ftp_pasv(). At the very least I'd like to know what's causing this error because the error returned is "unknown".

The error I keep seeing:

Warning: ftp_nlist(): bind() failed: Unknown error 4294967295 (-1) enter code here` in /base/data/home/apps/****/ftp.php on line 28

Here is the code, enter code here

```
$ftp_server = '****';
$connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
if(ftp_login($connection, '***', '****')) {
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);
    $filesList = ftp_nlist($connection, '.');
    print "<pre>"; print_r($filesList);
    foreach($filesList as $f) {
        $files = ftp_nlist($connection, $f);
        print "<pre>"; print_r($files);
    }
    ftp_close($connection);
} else {
    die('FTP Connection Failed');
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command on GAE, the problem is that ftp_nlist is attempting to write to GAE's local storage, which is not allowed. What you can try to do is inform it to use a temporary directory within Google Cloud Storage by setting the the temp dir environment variable:

```
putenv(‘TMPDIR=gs://bucket_name_to_write_temporary_files_to/’); //you can also declare a subdirectory if you want.
```

Call this before you attempt any ftp operations.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, But it doesn't help.